# Script to save matlab figures to a specified directory

Tags: matlab, save, figures

Suppose I have several figures open in matlab. I would like some function I can call, e.g `save_all_figures_to_directory('dir_name')`, that would iterate over all figures and save them to the specified folder. How do I do this?

Comment: very similar question: [How do I get the handles of all open figures in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540604/how-do-i-get-the-handles-of-all-open-figures-in-matlab)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Matlab function [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html):

```
function save_all_figures_to_directory(dir_name)
figlist=findobj('type','figure');
for i=1:numel(figlist)
    saveas(figlist(i),fullfile(dir_name,['figure' num2str(figlist(i)) '.fig']));
end
end
```

Comment: I like this little function- works well.  I'd love it to take the figure Name property as the figure "name".fig.  You can set the name property quite easily with a similar command: `figure('Name','ah3187w2070degspec1','NumberTitle','off','Color',[1 1 1])`  Note that I also turn off the number in the title as well as set the figure background color in that code.