# MATLAB: how to get the list of figures

Tags: matlab, figure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the handles of all open figures in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540604/how-do-i-get-the-handles-of-all-open-figures-in-matlab)

The situation is following. I run a couple of tests, which plot a lot of figures. I would like to convert them to pdf and compile into one file. Since each time I may get different type of plots and different number of plots, I need to get the list of all figures in current matlab session or workspace. Is this doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h = get(0,'Children');
```

will put the "handles" to the figures you currently have in the variable h.  `get(handle)` and `set(handle,...)` are gigantically useful in general.  The handle `0` points at the `root` of the display, so all the figures on the display are the root's `Children`.