# When I open a .fig from another figure in matlab gui doesn't work

Tags: matlab, user-interface, figure

I'm creating a gui with some gui , when I open a .fig from a figure with "open menu.fig" it opens good , but when I use a button to change some of the figure components properties with "set(handles.text1,'string',"123")" it doesn't work.
ERROR: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
but when I open this Fig in matlab not from another gui it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several possible reasons for this. Obviously the handles.text1 does not exist when you are calling "set(handles.text1,'string',"123")" . I guess you dont have the correct handle here...

The handles-structure only contains the handles of its own elements (well, by default.. you could append whatever you need if you want to)

To get a handle of another figure, you have to find the figure or the handle of the element directly. you can do this as explained here:

[how-do-i-get-the-handles-of-all-open-figures-in-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540604/how-do-i-get-the-handles-of-all-open-figures-in-matlab)

In your case

```
figHandles = findall(0,'Tag','text1');
```

would help, but only if there is just one element with this Tag!!

if you have the handle of the other figure (myFigure, you can use:

```
figHandles = findall(myFigure,'Tag','text1');
```

You could also use

```
output = open("menu.fig")
```

to get the handle of the new figure directly->

```
figHandles = findall(output ,'Tag','text1');
```

will do the job :)