# How do I save histogram to file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, save, histogram

```
figure;
histogram = hist(np,180);
name=['histogram-' int2str(k) '.png'];  
%% k is the iterator so basically I want to save all the images using a loop.
imwrite(out,name);
```

The image I got is only a horizontal line. Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use savefig instead of imwrite

here is the doc
http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html

```
savefig(h,filename)
```

h is the handle of figure. you could skip h to save the current figure.

(edit) savefig may not be there depending on the MATLAB version. In 2012b, it does not exit.

So [saveas](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) may be better:

```
f=figure;
hist([1 2 2 3]);
saveas(f, 'histogram-1.png')
```

This worked in MATALB 2012b. You can save it as .fig too.

Comment: I tried your method but it gave me an error "Undefined function 'savefig' for input arguments of type 'double'"

Comment: i see. probably you should get the handle from figure not from hist. So, fig = figure; and savefig(fig, "histogram-1.pgn"). I dont have matlab at moment so I am guessing.

Comment: I tried and failed again. And for the saveas command, I got an error "Invalid Simulink object handle"

Comment: huum. maybe try to get a handle this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/4540682/566035