# How to use histogram handler in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am trying to accumulate several `histogram` outputs into a `cell` array, but it seems that it's impossible to plot or do anything after the first execution of a single `histogram` command, because it's only an `handle to deleted Histogram`.

```
>> x = randn(10000,1);
>> h = histogram(x); 
>> h

h = 

  handle to deleted Histogram
>> whos h
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class                                        Attributes

  h         1x1               104  matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Histogram
```

I am aware that it's possible to write the histogram upon its calculation to a file, [How do I save histogram to file in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659044/how-do-i-save-histogram-to-file-in-matlab). Though I am trying to accumulate it into a cell array for later analysis.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now - after the figure is closed the handle is deleted.

Comment: I would say don't accumulate the handles, just accumulate the binned data from [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html), and only display them when you need to using [`bar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html). Any changes you want to apply to the plot should be done there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the [**BeingDeleted**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram-properties.html#property_BeingDeleted) property of **`histogram`** which can be read-only so you cannot change it.

However, you can copy the properties in another struct for later use. Modify your code as follows:

```
x = randn(10000,1);
h = histogram(x);
prop = properties(h);
for i = 1:length(prop)
    newh.(prop{i}) = h.(prop{i});
end
```

Now all the properties of `h` are stored in `newh` which will remain there even after you close the histogram figure.

Answer (score 2):

As has been suggested in comments, the proper way to do this, if all you need is the histogram values, is to use `histcounts`:

```
x = randn(10000,1);
[N,edges] = histcounts(x);
```

this way you can collect all bins x and y values (`edges` and `N`, respectively), and plot them later with `bar`. Here is a demonstration with a comparison between the results:

```
subplot 121
h = histogram(x)
title('histogram')
subplot 122
b = bar(edges(1:end-1),N,'FaceColor',lines(1),...
    'FaceAlpha',0.6)
title('bar')
```

[image: bar vs hist]

If it is important to show the histogram in the exact same way that `histogarm` does, you can set some more properties of `bar`.