# How to tell if a specific app is open and retrieve its window handle?

Tags: matlab, window, object-reference, handles, matlab-app-designer

How can we detect that an app is opened and get a handle to its app object?

Before, with `figure`, it was practical to use some `findobj` on the figure `'Tag'`. Then, we could check if it exists or not, and retrieve the content of the figure. But I didn't find how to manage it with an app.

Typically: I have a main app, that opens a new app window when I click on a button. Then, if I click on the button again, I want to check if the second app window is already opened or not, and if yes, take its app object, or delete the second window, etc. How can I capture this? Is there a way to capture it with `findobj` or similar function?

If I can avoid doing it by saving the app object with the `get/setappdata`, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a handle to the other window, I'd suggest creating a new property in your main app class that would store the 2<sup>nd</sup> app's handle, initialized to an empty graphic handle (`gobjects(0)`). Then, during the execution of the button callback, you check if this is a valid handle (`~isempty(h) &&`[`isvalid(h)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.isvalid.html)), and based on the result either create a new uifigure or use the existing one.

---

If you insist on obtaining a list of figure handles, then going over it and trying to find the right one based on known attributes such as the uifigure `Name` you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540637/3372061) answer:

```
hFigs = findall(groot, 'Type', 'figure');
```

If distinguishing between figure/uifigure windows is required/helpful, you can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47431214/3372061) technique afterwards:

```
hUIFigs = hFigs(arrayfun(@(x)isstruct(struct(x).ControllerInfo), hFigs));
```

---

Alternatively, to tell if an app is open you could call the following [undocumented function](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-uifigures-part-1):

```
webWindows = matlab.internal.webwindowmanager.instance.findAllWebwindows();
```

then compare the `'Title'` field of the returned objects to the one you're looking for.