# How to get the handles of all open App Designer apps (uifigures)?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, handle, object-reference, matlab-app-designer

As mentioned in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540637/3372061), it is possible to get the handles of all open figures using:

```
hFigs = findall(groot, 'Type', 'figure');
```

but this results in a list that contains both "old" `figure` and "new" `uifigure` handles.

How can I separate `hFigs` into two lists, one containing *only* `figure` and the other *only* `uifigure` references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To distinguish between `figure` and `uifigure` objects programatically, we can use a slight adaptation of what I suggested [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/348387-distinguish-uifigure-from-figure-programmatically#answer_278044):

```
function tf = isUIFigure(hFigList)
  tf = arrayfun(@(x)isstruct(struct(x).ControllerInfo), hFigList);
end
```

It's advised to have a couple of warnings turned off before calling the above, e.g.

```
% Turn off warnings:
ws(2) = warning('query','MATLAB:structOnObject');
ws(1) = warning('query','MATLAB:HandleGraphics:ObsoletedProperty:JavaFrame');
for indW = 1:numel(ws)
  warning('off', ws(indW).identifier);
end
% Call function:
tf = isUIFigure(hFigs);
% Restore the warnings' state:
warning(ws);
```

and to conclude:

```
hFigs = findall(groot, 'Type', 'figure');
isUIF = isUIFigure(hFigs);
hNewFigs = hFigs(isUIF);
hOldFigs = hFigs(~isUIF);
```

This solution was tested on R2017a and R2017b.