# Setting the default figure size of MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
set(gcf,'units','centimeters','position',[0 0 8.86 7.8])
```

This sets the size for a single figure in my matlab document, how do I do this for all figures plotted in my code?

Comment: Please see the relevant documentation [*here*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html)

Comment: Have already seen relevant documentation. Could you give an example using my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html), to change the default figure units and position, set the respective properties like this:

```
set(0, 'defaultFigureUnits', 'centimeters', 'defaultFigurePosition', [0 0 8.86 7.8]);
```

or in ≥ R2014b:

```
set(groot, 'defaultFigureUnits', 'centimeters', 'defaultFigurePosition', [0 0 8.86 7.8]);
```

---

If you don't want to change the default properties, you can get the handles of the currently opened figures as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540604/how-do-i-get-the-handles-of-all-open-figures-in-matlab) and use `set` to change the relevant properties of all in one go .